# How to select every (1918/1000)th record from SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL to select 1000 from 2000 records.

```
(SELECT 
        @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rownum,
        data.*,
        IF(@rownum % 2 = 1, '1', '2') AS grp,
```

But now I am required to select 1000 from 1918 using the same notation, order.

That means I need to do instead of 2 a value of 1.918

How to do that via the SQL?

Comment: Can you clarify please. What is "1000 from 2000 records", and what is "1000 from 1918"? Where does "1918/1000" come into it?

Comment: 1000 from 2000 records means to select every other record, and 1000 from 1918 means I need to select more than every other record, but only sometimes, and I can't figure out the clause.

Comment: What is your requirement? Do you need 1000 random rows from 1918 rows?

Comment: We need far more information about how you wish to overcome the fact that you only have integers to deal with. I mean in terms of precisely _which_ rows should be returned by this. Unless that's part of your question too :)

Comment: @Tomalak That's the problem I don't know how to figure it out.

Comment: In which case, this seems like a strange requirement. If you're not sure which rows you want, why do you think that you need this

Comment: @nobody I don't need by random, I need them in sequence. Every other 1.918 record.

Comment: There is no such thing as "every other 1.918 record".

Comment: I need to select 41 records more than just every other. And I need these 41 records to be distributed equally in the sequence.

Comment: How could they possibly be distributed equally? (Hint: they can't!) Also I'm not sure I quite understand your `GROUP BY` solution for retrieving every other row.

Comment: There is no group by here, it's just that IF.

Comment: this is easier to see as an ORDER BY issue. First you sort your sequence in the order you like your rows to be picked and then you SELECT ...... LIMIT 0 ,1918

Comment: The order by is there. The total records is 1918. I need to select 1000 from it sequentially.

Comment: @Pentium10: Er sorry yes. Never mind that question about `GROUP BY`; `grp` put me off ;)

Comment: @Pentium10: No, they will not be "sequential"... you wanted them distributed.

Comment: @Pentium10 so why wouldn't  `SELECT ...... LIMIT 0 ,1000` work for you?

Comment: @paolo that will select first 1000, and I need to select distributed 1000 from the set.

Comment: @Pentium10 yes... I was suggesting that usually in SQL the way to do that is to have a (even calculated) field on your table that allows you to ORDER BY in a way that puts the rows you want in the top, and then use LIMIT 0, number-of-rows-you-want, rather than deciding statistically row by row if you want to keep it or discard it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rownum,
  data.*,
  IF( FLOOR( @rownum % (1918.0/1000.0) ) = 0, '1', '2') AS grp
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with this:

```
IF(MOD(@rownum,2)=1 OR MOD(@rownum,1.918) BETWEEN 0.960 AND 1.040, '1', '2') AS grp,
```

Comment: There is no documentation for the ability of `MOD` to function like `fmod`. Are you sure that this is doing what you think it's doing?

Comment: Yeah, I see the results on my screen, they are OK.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod MOD() also works on values that have a fractional part and returns the exact remainder after division

Comment: I interpret that as only talking about the first parameter, and no example is given to the contrary.